# Select Mirror misses some faces

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

I have a model that looks symmetrical, but when I select the right leg and try to select the left leg with `Select` > `Select Mirror`, I got this:

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on here. Does it mean that my model isn't actually symmetrical? Also, what does "symmetrical" imply here? Topologically symmetrical? Or every single vertex needs to be the exactly opposite position?

Comment: For the mesh to be symmetrical e.g. on the X axis, for every single vertex _v_ with coordinates _(x, y, z)_ and it's symmetrical counterpart _v'_ with coordinates _(x', y', z') the equation _(x', y', z')_ = _(-x, y, z)_ has to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the model is not perfectly symmetrical.
Symmetrical means that every vertex is mirrored across the plane of one local axis.